# How do I make my React Bootstrap cards line up horizontally and equally spaced (also responsively if possible)

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap, reactstrap

I am using Reactstrap and displaying my cards dynamically and they seem to want to stack vertically no matter what I try. Here is the component in which they are rendered:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { CardDeck } from 'reactstrap';
import { fetchMerch } from '../actions/fetchMerchAction';
import { fetchUniqueMerch } from '../actions/fetchUniqueMerchAction';
import ItemCard from './ItemCard';
import shortid from 'shortid';

class ShopHome extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.onInitMerch();
  }

  showItemDetailHandler = (id) => {
    // console.log("*",id);
    this.props.onInitUniqueMerch(id);
    this.props.history.push(`detail/${this.props.id}`)
  }

  render() {

    let cards;
    if ( this.props.cards ) {
      cards = Object.values(this.props.cards).map( card => (
        <Link to={'/detail/' + card.id } key={`div-${shortid.generate()}`}>

              <ItemCard 
                key={card.id} 
                id={card.id} 
                title={card.title}
                price={card.price}
                image={card.img} 
                description={card.description}
                clicked={() => this.showItemDetailHandler(card.id)}
              />
        </Link>
        ) 
      )
    };
    return ( 
        <CardDeck>
          {cards}
        </CardDeck>     
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  // console.log("map props to state")
  // console.log("----->",state.data.cardData)
  return {
    cards: state.data.cardData,
    id: state.data.cardData
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    onInitMerch: () => dispatch(fetchMerch()),
    onInitUniqueMerch: (id) => dispatch(fetchUniqueMerch(id))
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ShopHome);
```

Here is the card component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import { Card, CardImg, CardText, CardBody,
  CardTitle, CardSubtitle } from 'reactstrap';
import './ItemCard.css';

class ItemCard extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
    <div>
      <Card className="card-style" onClick={this.props.clicked}>
        <CardImg top width="100%" src={this.props.image} alt="Card image cap" />
        <CardBody>
          <CardTitle >{this.props.title}</CardTitle>
          <CardSubtitle>${this.props.price}</CardSubtitle>
          <CardText>{this.props.description}</CardText>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(ItemCard);
```

Here is the ItemCard.css:

```
.card-style {
  max-width: 30%;
}
```

If I give the cards a fixed size with inline styling: style={{width: 20 + 'rem'}} the cards line up horizontally but I cannot center them on the page. They line up a little to the left. I just want a three card row centered and evenly spaced.

Comment: I am not an expert in React but I think that sharing ItemCard.css could help us to answer.

Comment: Just edited post and added it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use `style={{display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'row'}}` on the CardDeck and then put `style={{flex: 1}}` on the card.

They should fill up the remaining space. One thing is to make sure to provide the size that you want the CardDeck to be.

More info on flexbox [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added a width of 100% to the CardDeck and added the styles you posted, but that seems to return the same results.

Comment: Add `justifyContent: center` to the CardDeck

Comment: Finally got it. I had to use em instead of % on the card width for some reason. Then I did what you said @shkfnly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @shkfnly I am also facing the same problem but It's not working with the above instructions
My code Link is : https://stackoverflow.com/q/62277219/7583640

Comment: Your answer is really helpful @shkfnly. I am wondering if there could be a more elegant way to achieve the same.